# Firefox not starting onreadystatechange function

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, xmlhttprequest

I made some javascript code for my website, it works without problem on opera and chrome, but not on firefox.

Here is script:

```
function checkstate(who,row,cell)   {
    var zwrot="";
    var mouseEvent='onmouseover="javascript:bubelon(this.id);" onmouseout="bubeloff();"';
    var cellid="";

    ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.onreadystatechange=function(aEvt) {
        if (ajax.readyState===4 && ajax.status===200) {
            alert("im here!");
            }
    };

    ajax.open('GET',"oth/work_prac_stan.php?usr="+who,false);
    ajax.send();
}

function sprawdzstan() {
    var lol="";
    var table = document.getElementById("usery");
    var re = /^<a\shref\=/g;

    for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i ++) {
        if (row.cells[0].innerHTML.match(re)) {
            checkstate(row.cells[1].innerHTML,row,2);
        } else {
            checkstate(row.cells[0].innerHTML,row,1);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, that firefox is not running function assigned to onreadystatechange. I checked in firebug, that response from php file is correct.

Where is the problem? It works on chrome and opera, firefox just dont, no error in console, nothing.

Comment: Just change the request type from synchronous to asynchronous... as `ajax.open('GET',"oth/work_prac_stan.php?usr="+who,true);` ... in my case it worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Updated answer

According to [Mozilla's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest#onreadystatechange), you don't use `onreadystatechange` with synchronous requests. Which kind of makes sense, since the request doesn't return until the ready state is 4 (completed), though I probably wouldn't have designed it that way.

### Original answer

Not immediately seeing a smoking gun, but: Your `ajax` variable is not defined within the function, and so you're almost certainly overwriting it on every iteration of the loop in `sprawdzstan`. Whether that's a *problem* remains to be seen, since you're using a synchronous ajax call. In any case, add a `var ajax;` to `checkstate` to ensure that you're not falling prey to the [Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

---

**Off-topic**: If you can possibly find a way to refactor your design to *not* use a synchronous ajax request, strongly recommend doing that. Synchronous requests lock up the UI of the browser (to a greater or lesser degree depending on the browser, but many — most? — *completely* lock up, including other unrelated tabs). It's almost always possible to refactor and use an asynchronous request instead.

**Off-topic 2**: You aren't using `mouseEvent` in your code, but if you were, you would want to get rid of those `javascript:` prefixes on the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` attributes. Those attributes are not URLs, the prefix is not (there) a protocol specifier (it's a label, which you're not using).

Comment: I would say 'var *keyword*'. And +1 for the capitalised 'Horror of Implicit Globals' (HOIG) :), in addition to the sound suggestion.

Comment: added var as here: "var ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();" no difference, still dont work.

Comment: @WombaT: Found it (by searching with a popular search engine -- I didn't know beforehand -- and finding a reply to the same sort of question from Richard Cornford, who's fairly knowledgeable about this stuff; then went and checked the MDC docs). Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

For those who still encounter this problem...

You can use the below code. What I did is remove the function

```
ajax.onreadystatechange=function(aEvt) {
```

and transfer the alert("im here!"); after the ajax.send();

```
ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();

ajax.open('GET',"oth/work_prac_stan.php?usr="+who,false);
ajax.send();

alert("im here!");
```